# Documentation for # keywords such as #as?

Tags: kframework

Is there documentation somewhere for what keywords such as `#as` are available and how to use them?

Particularly does `#as` in `<k> S:Set </k> #as ASET` mean `ASET` is a Set or equal to the cell `k` containing `S` inside it?

Is the syntax `<k> ... SetItem(X) ... #as S </k>` valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation for `#as` patterns: https://github.com/kframework/k/blob/master/pending-documentation.md#as-patterns

In your first example:

```
<k> S:Set </k> #as KCELL
```

Would bind variable `S` to the actual `Set` that the `<k>` cell contains, and would bind `KCELL` to the entire `<k>`-cell term `<k> S:Set </k>`.

In your second example (modified):

```
<k> (REST SetItem(X)) #as S </k>
```

you would get `X` bound to the element that is picked out (with no constraints on it, it will pick non-deterministically), `REST` bound to the remainder of the set without that element, and `S` bound to the entire set.

Comment: In the documentation, if the #as pattern is used around a rewrite, my understanding is that the result of the rewrite is bound to the variable. Is this the case? e.g. would the following pattern map the entire set in <k> where X is replaced for Y to variable S? `<k> (... SetItem(X) => SetItem(Y) ...) #as S </k>`

Comment: The `#as` pattern will be the LHS of the rewrite, it always matches the pre-state.